# Huawei EVA-L09 removes short songs from music player

Tags: file-system, music, huawei, file-management, music-player

I have noticed that there are some songs not displaying in my music player on my android phone.

What is interesting, is that these files are no different from ones I do see in my player. And I can still find them and play them using ES File Explorer. But they do not show up in my music library.

What all these songs have in common, is that they are short. Filler tracks, if you will. Tracks no more than 1 minute.

They are the only ones that consistently don't show up in my library, no matter how many times I try to put them on my phone (through dropbox). Like I said though, they exist on my phone and I can find and play them, the problem is that they don't show up in my library.

I just want to have my albums complete! Is there some setting I am missing here?

Thanks,

-slightly annoyed Android user

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out. On the main page of the music library there is a gear at the top left where you can modify the filter settings for how short a track has to be to stop appearing in your library. Moving the slider to 0 seconds solved my issue.